# ESP32 restart each minute with SW_CPU_RESET

Tags: esp32

running an ESP32 (ttgo), I get strange behavior.  The unit restarts each minute, around 00 seconds.

I get
`12:31:02.861 -> rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)`
as reason.

I checked flash frequency is 40MHz (80 seems to lead to same issues)

Anyway, if I start the device at 10:00:34, it will restart at 10:01:00 and then at 10:02:00 and so on ...

running this code:   https://github.com/xlyric/pv-router-esp32

Powered by a usb-C phone-power, or on computer usb does the same.

The ttgo is plugged on a board connected to a AC/AC transformer and a current mesure device.

using "esp_register_shutdown_handler", I succed to send a mqtt message "gonna die",  it really rise each minute at 00 seconds

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information to anwer it. Describe your setup. What code is your ESP32 running? What power supply is it connected to? What other hardware is connected to it?

Comment: Thanks all, bug was between chair and keyboard :-) I was getting http calls on "/reset" from a crazy domoticz instance

Answer (score 2):

The restart reason suggests that the ESP32 restarts upon software restart command. One should go over the code and see where in the code the restart command is sent. For instance starting from line 451 there is following:

```
if (config.restart) {
    //delay(5000);
    Serial.print(PV_RESTART);
    ESP.restart();
  }
```